# How does iOS determine when to switch bitrates while doing adaptive streaming over HLS?

Tags: ios, streaming, wowza, adaptive-bitrate

Everything that I can find while searching just mentions that the adaptive bitrate switching is automatic.  Is there any specific information on how a switch from a higher bitrate to a lower bitrate is triggered, and does an iOS app developer have any control over when this occurs?

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, but the streams will switch based on the network bandwidth availability at the end user.

Comment: i'd like to add that serious adaptive bitrate players make their decisions based on CPU load, player size and of course bandwidth.

Comment: some usefull links: http://www.encoding.com/iphonestreaming  and http://gravlab.com/2012/05/09/ios-and-mobile-video-playback-perfection/